# Telegram Bot, problems with data

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I have a telegram channel. Through the bot, I make a post with four inline buttons (1, 2, 3, 4) and a certain explanation text for the buttons, when I click on the buttons in different posts, I get the same Callback to all posts:

- 1 post - (pressed 1 - Aaaa, pressed 2 - Bbb ... etc) here through State did 1. Aaaa, 2. Bbb...
- 2 post - (pressed 1 - Aaaa, pressed 2 - Bbb ... etc) here through State did 1. Eeee, 2. Fff...

How to make callback.answer output its own text to each post? For example:

- 1 post (clicked on one of the four buttons - it turned out "Yes, that's right, it's Gogol")
- 2 post (clicked on one of the four buttons - it turned out "Yes, Well done, it's Bunin")

With the help of the bot, it is planned to post a lot of posts. So.. maybe sqlite3..? But How?
(python, aiogram3)
I tried to make a sqlite3 database, but I never figured it out..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.  Unfortunately, I don't quite understand what you're doing; but perhaps someone might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can encode post ID and button ID in the callback_data:

Define class:

```
class PostButtonCallbackData(CallbackData, prefix="post_btn_"):
    post_id: int
    btn_id: int
```

To create your buttons use code like this:

```
post_id = 112233 # Generate and store this unique post ID

kb_btns = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    cb_data = PostButtonCallbackData(post_id=post_id, btn_id=i).pack()
    kb_btns.append(
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(i), callback_data=cb_data)]
    )

reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=kb_btns)

# use this reply_markup when you send post
```

To handle callbacks use filter:

```
@router.callback_query(PostButtonCallbackData.filter())
async def cb_post_btn_clicked(callback: CallbackQuery, callback_data: PostButtonCallbackData):
    post_id = callback_data.post_id
    btn_id = callback_data.btn_id
    # Do whatever you need
    pass
```

**I haven't run this code and it may contain errors, but I hope this will help you to find the direction.**

Comment: This solves the problem, but if the program is interrupted (ctrl+c), the data won't be saved( But thanks anyway

Comment: Of course you should use datbase to store information about posts. Using sqlite is quite simple. You can find documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-tutorial

Comment: thanks, I'll try